# Azure AGIC addon

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-cli, azure-aks

I am facing a error below when I tried to enable app gateway addon for aks

```
az aks enable-addons -n pocakscluster -g POC-RG -a ingress-appgw --appgw-id $appgwId
```

***UnrecognizedArgumentError: unrecognized arguments: --appgw-id /subscriptions/#####&&&&/resourceGroups/POC-RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/pocappgw***

AKS is running on version 1.17.X
AppGW has WAF_v2 SKU

The same command was working fine earlier

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing these CLI commands from your MAC? If yes it looks like there is some issue with MAC version of CLI. Please continue using cloud shell for now. Let us know if you can execute from cloud shell or not.

Comment: I was not using mac. I tried it on cloud CLI and using windows powershell as well but the results were identical (got same error). However you can refer the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az_aks_enable_addons there is no such option ( --appgw-id) with az aks enable-addons command. It's pretty suspicious cause same command worked fine on Thursday (i.e. November 12)